# Postgres: test insert or update before doing it?

Tags: postgresql, testing, transactions, rollback

We have a table that only ever contains one entry of a particular type, so if we get an request for an insert we delete everything and then do the insert. The insert comes from user data and there have been times where it throws an error (maybe they didn't fill something in, etc) and we end up with a bunch of deleted data. We are handling all the data processing so we don't have error like that anymore but I was wondering:

Is there a way to test an insert or update to see if it will work before actually doing it?

Comment: Sounds like you should use database transactions: rollback on errors, commit on success.

Answer (score 4):

Open a session and do everything in a [transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-begin.html):

```
BEGIN;
INSERT ...

-- check if it worked
ROLLBACK;
```

Everything will be rolled back. Some possible side effects, though: incremented sequences are not reset. Some functions like `dblink()` cannot be rolled back. Plain `INSERT` or `UPDATE` are safe. Be aware that you may be locking rows as long as your transaction is open.

**However**, if you are operating with valuable data, you shouldn't toy with it like that. Create a copy of your database for testing.